# Python / Flask google api integration

Tags: python, flask, google-api, google-api-python-client

I'm new to Python as well as in Flask... I have developed an python file which sets up the Oauth2 authentication with googele and fetching the list of messages from GMAIL API. Here is my code

```
import json
import flask
import httplib2
import base64
import email

from apiclient import discovery, errors
from oauth2client import client


app = flask.Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    if 'credentials' not in flask.session:
        return flask.redirect(flask.url_for('oauth2callback'))
    credentials = client.OAuth2Credentials.from_json(flask.session['credentials'])
    if credentials.access_token_expired:
        return flask.redirect(flask.url_for('oauth2callback'))
    else:
        http_auth = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
        gmail_service = discovery.build('gmail', 'v1', http_auth)
        threads = gmail_service.users().threads().list(userId='me').execute()
        return json.dumps(threads)


@app.route('/oauth2callback')
def oauth2callback():
    flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(
        'client_secrets.json',
        scope='https://mail.google.com/',
        redirect_uri=flask.url_for('oauth2callback', _external=True)
    )
    if 'code' not in flask.request.args:
        auth_uri = flow.step1_get_authorize_url()
        return flask.redirect(auth_uri)
    else:
        auth_code = flask.request.args.get('code')
        credentials = flow.step2_exchange(auth_code)
        flask.session['credentials'] = credentials.to_json()
        return flask.redirect(flask.url_for('index'))

@app.route('/getmail')
def getmail():
    if 'credentials' not in flask.session:
        return flask.redirect(flask.url_for('oauth2callback'))
    credentials = client.OAuth2Credentials.from_json(flask.session['credentials'])
    if credentials.access_token_expired:
        return flask.redirect(flask.url_for('oauth2callback'))
    else:
        http_auth = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
        gmail_service = discovery.build('gmail', 'v1', http_auth)
        query = 'is:inbox'
        """List all Messages of the user's mailbox matching the query.

        Args:
        service: Authorized Gmail API service instance.
        user_id: User's email address. The special value "me"
        can be used to indicate the authenticated user.
        query: String used to filter messages returned.
        Eg.- 'from:user@some_domain.com' for Messages from a particular sender.

        Returns:
        List of Messages that match the criteria of the query. Note that the
        returned list contains Message IDs, you must use get with the
        appropriate ID to get the details of a Message.
        """
        try:
            response = gmail_service.users().messages().list(userId='me', q=query).execute()
            messages = []
            if 'messages' in response:
                print 'test %s' % response
                messages.extend(response['messages'])
            while 'nextPageToken' in response:
                page_token = response['nextPageToken']
                response = gmail_service.users().messages().list(userId='me', q=query, pageToken=page_token).execute()
                messages.extend(response['messages'])

            return messages
        except errors.HttpError, error:
            print 'An error occurred: %s' % error

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import uuid
    app.secret_key = str(uuid.uuid4())
    app.debug = True
    app.run()
```

Authentication works fine and when I go to `/getmail` URL I am getting this error `TypeError: 'list' object is not callable`

Any thoughts what I am doing wrong?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27608987/typeerror-list-object-is-not-callable-flask) maybe it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed return object in Flask from `return messages` to this piece of code.

First I imported to `from flask.json import jsonify`

```
try:
    response = gmail_service.users().messages().list(userId='me', q=query).execute()
    messages = []
    if 'messages' in response:
        print 'test %s' % response
        messages.extend(response['messages'])
    while 'nextPageToken' in response:
        page_token = response['nextPageToken']
        response = gmail_service.users().messages().list(userId='me', q=query, pageToken=page_token).execute()
        messages.extend(response['messages'])

    return jsonify({'data': messages}) # changed here
except errors.HttpError, error:
    print 'An error occurred: %s' % error
```

all credit goes to @doru